# Function name in if condition in shell

Tags: linux, shell

What will be expression value if function name is used as an expression in shell script if-else statement?

In the following shell script, after function is **returning error** on **failure** which is **non zero** but the control is entering in else statement. Why?

```
#!/bin/sh                                              
test_internet()                                                               
{
        printf "Checking for internet connectivity : \t"                        
        ping -c 4 -q www.google.com                                             
        retval=$?                                                               
        echo $retval                                                            
        if [ $retval != 0 ]                                                     
        then                                                                    
                return "$retval"                                                
        fi                                                                      
}                                                                         
main()                                                                          
{                                                                               
        if test_internet ; then                                                 
                printf "test passed\n"                                          
        else                                                                    
                printf "failed\n"                                               
        fi                                                                                
}                                                                               
main
```

Comment: The function is called. That simple.

Answer (score 1):

A function in an if statement is **nothing special**. The function is called and its return value is regarded (zero = true, non-zero = false).

From `man 1 bash`:

```
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
    The if list is executed.  If its exit status is zero, the then list is executed.  Otherwise, each elif list is executed in turn, and if its exit status is zero, the corresponding then list is
    executed and the command completes.  Otherwise, the else list is executed, if present.  The exit status is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero if no condition tested true.
```

So whatever after the keyword `if` is simply executed, and its return value is used for the condition checking.

Just like you would normally check for equality of numbers, you can get a visual report like this:

```
# if [ 1 -eq 2 ]; then do_something; fi
[ 1 -eq 2 ]; echo $?
```